# ng-controller breaks angular parsing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to learn Angular.js and I have a simple fiddle that should work according to the tutorial (at least I think it should) but clearly it doesn't.

A directive before the 'data-ng-controller' works but the same directive after fails. Thanks.

I've tried camelcase variants and traditional ng-directive variants. According to the docs - data-ng-directive should be valid as a workaround for html validation.

http://jsfiddle.net/p458q/

### html:

```
<div ng-app="">
    <h3>{{ "test" }}</h3>
    <div data-ng-controller="ItemListCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{ item.description }}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h3>{{ "test" }}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

### js:

```
function ItemListCtrl ($scope) {
 $scope.items = [
  { "description": "coffee pot" },
  { "description": "nerf gun" },
  { "description": "phone" }
 ];
}
```

Comment: Here is the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/p458q/18/

Comment: I would suggest using plnkr.co as it has prebuilt angular templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't work correctly, because there are some things missing:

1) You must define a module for your app, and that module must be referenced in the DOM via ng-app

```
var app = angular.module('test', [])
```

2) For angular to work in jsfiddle, you must select "no wrap -in " in the second select box under Frameworks & Extensions

See http://jsfiddle.net/p458q/16/

With these changes, your fiddle works as aexpected. I don't think there's a problem with data-..., at least I don't see it from the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks! Though for the sake of my learning - I've set up a similar situation in a static site tool I use and it works sans app declaration (just ng-app="") why would that be? Thanks again for the help.